# Why covariance matrix estimation error is high when the matrix is close to singularity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance, singularity

According to the research paper ['An alternative approach for solving the problem of close to singular covariance matrices in modern portfolio theory'](http://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=8931835&fileOId=8931842), if a matrix ($ \Sigma\ $) is close to singularity, the inverted covariance matrix ($ \Sigma^{-1}\ $) contains high estimation error.

> ... the sample covariance matrix approaches
>   singularity. Both problems lead to uncertainties in form of estimation error. ....

I have tried hard to figure out why the inverted covariance matrix ($ \Sigma^{-1}\ $) high estimation error (=poor quality) when the covariance matrix ($ \Sigma\ $)is close to singularity but cannot figure out why. Any explanation in plain English would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the $n\times p$ matrix of data ($n$ observations and $p$ features). If the data is centered, the estimated covariance matrix is $\hat{\Sigma}=n^{-1}X^{T}X$. This matrix, as the original $\Sigma$, is non-negative definite (all its eigenvalues are $\geq 0$). If $\lambda_1\geq \cdots\geq \lambda_p\geq 0$ are the eigenvalues of $\hat{\Sigma}$, you can diagonalize it as 
$$
\hat{\Sigma}=P\text{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_p)P^{T},
$$
for some orthogonal matrix $P$. And its inverse is of course 
$$
\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}=P\text{diag}(\lambda_1^{-1},...,\lambda_p^{-1})P^{T}.
$$
If $X$ has rank $< p$ (for example if $n<p$), then there exist some $\lambda_i=0$ and you can not compute $\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}$. So if you have some $\lambda_i\approx 0$, the estimation of $\Sigma^{-1}$, i.e, $\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}$ will be unstable (some of its elements will explode), in particular $\text{trace}(\hat{\Sigma}^{-1})$ will approach infinity.

I recommend you the book "Large Sample Covariance Matrices and High‑Dimensional Data Analysis" by Yao, et. al. for more on the estimation of $\Sigma$ when $p>n$.

Comment: Why is $ \Sigma\ $ = $ \ n^{-1} X^{T} X\ $? I meant, this part $ \ X^{T} X \ $ And the rest of your explanation is a bit hard for me to understand. can you introduce me a book or a video lecture which is a bit more toned down?

Comment: First formula: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G16c2ZODcg8. Positive matrices: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojUQk_GNQbQ. Diagonalization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8R54zOTVLw. If you are gonna work with covariance matrices I'll strongly recommend being fluent in the kind of concepts that I presented in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix and $w$ is the vector of investments, then $w^T\Sigma w$ is the variance of the portfolio. Suppose $\Sigma$ is almost singular, then there is an eigenvector $v$ for which the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is close to $0$. Taking $w=v$, you get variance $\lambda w^Tw$. Being able to make an investment with near $0$ variance can be an arbitrage opportunity depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But my question is about when the matrix is close to singular, but you are saying that covariance matrix is close to singular. Are they equal?

Comment: @Eiffelbear the true covariance matrix and the sample covariance matrix are almost never equal, but since you do not know the true matrix in practice, the sample covariance matrix is used as an estimator

Comment: @LingAlg Actually I am still having a hard time understanding your answer. From your answer 'Taking w=v, you get variance λwTw', where did that λwTw come from? Can you elaborate on this part by adding the explanation on this bit to your answer, please? It seems like a big leap to me.

Comment: @Eiffelbear Just plugging it into the formula of the variance, and using that $v$ is an eigenvector of $\Sigma$: $w^T\Sigma w = w^T (\Sigma v) = w^T (\lambda v) = \lambda w^Tw$

Comment: Thank you but Can I ask you three more questions? 
Q1. Let's say the matrix is in m*n shape. m here is the number of observations and n here is the number of features. Why does the covariance matrix approaches singularity when n is close to or bigger than m? 
Q2. Why is the eigenvalue of the matrix (close to) 0 when the matrix is (almost) singular? 
Q3. When the eigenvalue of a covariance matrix is close to 0, why is the quality of the covariance matrix is bad? In other words, why is the value of variance and covariance parameters of the covariance matrix not accurate?

Comment: @Eiffelbear Q1: the rank of the $n\times n$ covariance matrix cannot exceed $m$, so if $m<n$, the matrix is singular; Q2: the matrix $\Sigma$ is singular if $\Sigma x = 0$ has a nontrivial solution, such a solution $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$. Q3: This depends on the context, but being able to make an investment with near 0 variance is an arbitrage opportunity; so under the assumption of absence of arbitration opportunities, that should not happen.

Comment: Q2. It is true that x is a eigenvector if the equation that you have given has a non-trivial solution. But shouldn't we calculate the equation $ \Sigma\ $x = $ \lambda\ $x to get the eigenvalue? How can we be so sure that the eigenvalue is 0? Q3. Actually, what I am more interested in is the __estimation error__ of the inverted covariance matrix, not arbitration. Research papers say that the covariance matrix of the m * n matrix approaches singularity when __n__ (number of daily prices, for example) is not considerably bigger than __m__ (number of assets).

Comment: And I finally came up with my __real question.__ Sorry for not clarifying my question for so long. When the $ \Sigma\ $ approaches singularity, the $ \Sigma^{-1}\ $ contains lots of error in it. So what I am curious to know is __why__ $ \Sigma^{-1}\ $ has lots of computational errors in it (resulting in poor estimation of the inverse of covariance matrix) when the $ \Sigma\ $ is close to singularity. I also corrected the content of the question to better clarify what I am curious to figure out.

Comment: Q2: if a nonzero $x$ satisfies $\Sigma x=0$, then what could the eigenvalue of eigenvector $x$ possibly be? Q3: just think about the real numbers. If $x$ is close to $0$, a relatively small change of $x$ creates a large change in $1/x$

Comment: Q2. Let's say that the covariance matrix is n*n matrix. Then are you saying that all n eigenvalues are 0? Q3. What is the relationship between x and 1/x and matrix and inverted matrix? Are you giving me a metaphor? I always appreciate your answers. Thank you.

Comment: Q2: no, just one eigenvalue; Q3: the simplest example is a 1x1 matrix

Comment: Can you be more specific, for example giving examples, when you explain your answers? You answered like " what else it can be than 0?" and then said out of n eigenvalues, only one is 0. So it is difficult for me to follow your train of thougts.